# Compressed (Zipped) Folders no longer extract properly

Tags: windows

I actually just finished up cleaning a virus from my computer (took me in total like 20 minutes, no big deal), but I'm almost sure this is what caused the problem. Now, whenever I download a zipfile I can open it but it will not extract. The Windows Explorer extractor acts like everything went fine, but all it does is create the folder if it doesn't exist and then extract nothing. I also cannot open any file in the zipped folder.

Comment: Did you try to Repair it?

Comment: Er, not sure what you mean. Repair what?

Comment: What virus? That may help determining if/how it could be related.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the virus may have damaged Windows.  Open up an administrator command prompt. if you dont know how, click `Start`, then enter in the `Run` box `cmd` and hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  In the command prompt type `sfc /scannow`.  This command will have windows check all its files and replace them if they are damaged.

Comment: Thank you, I will do this now and then update when it's finished.

Comment: Okay, Keltari, so I did that twice and each time it would stop at 58% and say "Windows Resource Protection could not complete the requested operation". That doesn't look good.

Comment: No, that doesnt sound good.  Personally, I dont trust systems that have been compromised by a virus, especially one thats not behaving well.  If it were me, I would back up the important data and reinstall.  Better safe, than sorry.  Plus, troubleshooting may take longer than just blowing it away and starting fresh.

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-enable the built-in support for zip archives, as described here: http://codesociety.com/2009/07/27/disable-zip-folders-in-windows-7-vista-xp/

If you're using Windows Xp, you must:

1. Go to Start Menu -> Run.
2. paste the following command and press enter: **regsvr32 %windir%\system32\zipfldr.dll**
3. Restart Windows and return to a life bound by zip folders!

For Windows Vista:

1. Download [vistaenablezip.reg](http://codesociety.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/vistaenablezip.reg) and run it (double-click).
2. Restart Windows.

On Windows 7 the procedure is a bit more long, see *To Enable Zip Folders* on [sevenforums.com](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/13619-zip-folders-enable-disable-windows-explorer-view.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to open it (double click). When it requests what application to open it with then specify Windows Explorer. This resets the default Windows Explorer unzipping utility.

I had installed WinZip on my Windows 7 64 bit machine to try something with a very large file. When I did that it replaced the default Windows Explorer tool. Then, when I uninstalled WinZip the application did not default back to Windows Explorer. Rather, my machine didn't know what to do. The file folders simply appeared as white square type icons. Once I respecified to use Windows Explorer all went well and files were extracted as they had been before.